# Is there anyway to get javascript error on android or iphone mobile webkit browser?

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, webkit

I have built a website for mobile webkit browsers, there is an interval update to refresh data. But it turns out that the pooling refresh will stop at some time after run for a while (some minutes or hours, different by each time).

I thought there may be something error occurred in my refresh data functions, but it works well in my laptop browser. I also tried to listen window.onerror event, but webkit browser seems do not support that event. What else can I do?

And I am also doubting is there any problem with setTimeout and setInterval functions in mobile webkit browser?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to enable Debug Console on your iphone?
Settings > Safari > Developer

Comment: actually i only have an android phone on hand.

Comment: how about the iPhone simulator? You can do the same on that.

Comment: @willi: There is no option you mentioned in iOS 6.1. Do you know where I can find the option now?

Comment: You have to enable your device for development in Xcode Organizer.